# Using preg_replace and ignoring special characters

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I've two strings of the type:

```
$s1 = hello <em>worlds</em>
$s2 = Hello World's
```

I want the `$s2` to become `Hello <em>World's</em>`

I'm trying to implement this in the following manner:

```
preg_match_all('/<em>(.+?)<\/em>/i', $s1, $hits);
foreach ($hits[1] as $hit) {
    $s2 = preg_replace($hit, '<em>$0</em>', $s2);
}
```

It's not doing on strings ($s2) which might have special characters.

There might be multiple instances of `<em>` tags, or different cases of uppercase-lowercase For eg.:

```
$s1 = <em>hellos</em> <em>where</em> are <em>you</em>? 
$s2 = hello's where are YOU?
```

**EDIT**

I don't want to use any HTML parser. I'm looking for a solution suing PHP without any parsers. I went quite far in trying to achieve a solution. So, I'm hopeful that there must be a way to do it without parsers and using `preg_*` functions.

Comment: have you tried considering an HTML parser instead?

Comment: @Ghost: I don't want to use any HTML parser.

Answer (score -1):

Problems like Yours here, are mostly signals that You have lost right path in Your project some time ago...

But if You like to play messy, You can dynamically build Your patterns, and expect some custom set of special chars everywhere. Below is little example of how this can be done.

```
<?php
# Array of chars You want to ignore. 
# Make sure to esape special chars as perceived in [] brackets.
$special_chars_array = array("'","\[");

$s1 = "hello <em>worlds</em>";
$s2 = "Hello W[orld's";
preg_match_all("/<em>(.+?)<\/em>/i", $s1, $hits);
# Make set from Your char array, or You cloud insert "?" after each char - as You see fit
$special_chars_pattern = sprintf("[%s]?",implode("",$special_chars_array));
foreach ($hits[1] as $hit) 
{
    # Some messing with strings and arrays to get what is needed
    $pattern = implode($special_chars_pattern,str_split($hit)).$special_chars_pattern;
    echo sprintf('For hit "%s" pattern "%s" was made.',$hit,$pattern);
    $s2 = preg_replace(sprintf('#%s#i',$pattern), '<em>$0</em>', $s2);
}
echo '<pre>';
echo $s2;
echo '</pre>';
```